# Wicket RepeatingView: delete placeholder if list is empty

Tags: java, html, wicket, wicket-6

I'm using the wicket `RepeatingView` to implement a list of items. The HTML is as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li wicket:id="listItemFoo">
        ...content...
    </li>
</ul>
```

And on the java backend I do:

```
RepeatingView listFoo = new RepeatingView("listItemFoo");
//put items inside listFoo
addOrReplace(listFoo);
```

This works corretly, but it has one problem. There are cases in my application where there are NO items to add to the list. In that case I'd like the repeater to output nothing. However, this isn't the case: if the repeater in empty it will still output a single, empty `<li></li>`.
This is annoying because it displays an empty bullet point in the page. What is the correct way to avoid this? (I know it might be trivial, but I'm very new to wicket as you can probably tell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:

```
<ul>
    <wicket:container wicket:id="listItemFoo">
        <li>
            ...content...
        </li>
    </wicket:container>                         
</ul>
```

This way, when the list is empty the container won't even be generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the RepeatingView in a container and turn that invisible when the list is empty.

```
WebMarkupContainer container = new WebMarkupContainer("listItemFooContainer");
RepeatingView listFoo = new RepeatingView("listItemFoo");
// add items here
container.add(listFoo);
if (yourlist.isEmpty()) {
    container.setVisible(false);
}
```

In the html you can do:

```
<ul wicket:id="listItemFooContainer">
    <li wicket:id="listItemFoo">
    ...
```

Or do this

```
<div wicket:id="listItemFooContainer">
<ul>
    <li wicket:id="listItemFoo">
    ...
```

Comment: Upvoted, although I found a quicker way that I ended up using (see my own answer)

Comment: You could also do `view.setVisible(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list))`

Comment: You're right martin-g, but this means you always set it to visible if it the list is not empty, this could disturb making it invisible somewhere else.